# Kibana:- To create custom field for fetching bytes/packets data in vpcflow logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana-4

With the help of shell script, my VPC flow logs are getting transferred to kibana but the full log data gets into the field of **message** type like this.

> 2 123456789010 eni-abc123de 172.168.1.12 172.168.1.11 20641 22 6 20 4249 1418530010 1418530070 ACCEPT OK

Now, message type contains everything like srcaddr, portaddr, bytes, packets, etc data and from there I wanted to have separate field for bytes and packets so that I can create a dashboard to know how traffic is flowing in/out of my VPC.

Can you please suggest how can I get that data?